# Hyperledger Fabric function renaming leads to error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, chaincode

I am playing with `fabcar` example in Hyperledger Fabric. There, in the chaincode, I changed `queryAllCars` function name to `queryAllProducts` and then changed that method name in the `query.js` file where is being consumed. But I am getting following error due to non-existing function. I checked all places by the name of the queryAllCars function usage, but cannot figure out the issue. What is the root cause for this issue?

```
2019-06-23T04:14:37.101Z - warn: [Query]: evaluate: Query ID "[object Object]" of peer "peer0.ibo.bc4scm.de" failed: message=transaction returned with failure: Error: You've asked to invoke a function that does not exist: queryAllProducts, stack=Error: transaction returned with failure: Error: You've asked to invoke a function that does not exist: queryAllProducts
at self._endorserClient.processProposal (/home/malintha/Academic/3rd_Semester/DLT4PI/BCNetwork/BC4SCM/FrontEndCalls/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Peer.js:140:36)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/malintha/Academic/3rd_Semester/DLT4PI/BCNetwork/BC4SCM/FrontEndCalls/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1207:9)
at InterceptingListener._callNext (/home/malintha/Academic/3rd_Semester/DLT4PI/BCNetwork/BC4SCM/FrontEndCalls/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:568:42)
at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/home/malintha/Academic/3rd_Semester/DLT4PI/BCNetwork/BC4SCM/FrontEndCalls/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:618:8)
at callback (/home/malintha/Academic/3rd_Semester/DLT4PI/BCNetwork/BC4SCM/FrontEndCalls/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:845:24), status=500, , url=grpc://localhost:7051, name=peer0.ibo.bc4scm.de, grpc.max_receive_message_length=-1, grpc.max_send_message_length=-1, grpc.keepalive_time_ms=120000, grpc.http2.min_time_between_pings_ms=120000, grpc.keepalive_timeout_ms=20000, grpc.http2.max_pings_without_data=0, grpc.keepalive_permit_without_calls=1, name=peer0.ibo.bc4scm.de, request-timeout=300000, isProposalResponse=true
Failed to evaluate transaction: Error: transaction returned with failure: Error: You've asked to invoke a function that does not exist: queryAllProducts
```

Answer (score 1):

When ever you change/edit the chaincode you have to install and instantiate it again to the peers.
I would suggest please install the chaincode with a new version
you would find that part in the startfabric.sh script in the chaincode install section. 
it would look something like this.

```
 peer chaincode install \
        -n fabcar \
        -v 1.0 \
        -p "$CC_SRC_PATH" \
    -l "$CC_RUNTIME_LANGUAGE"
```

change it for both the peers.

or
you can Delete the old chaincode manually which are already installed in the peer.